# System drive incremental clone

Tags: backup

I would have a question that will get a "-1" rating.

I once daily backup my data drive to a clone drive with SynckBack, which compares both disks and mirrors the copy to the original, just updating by adding/deleting files. Easy and fast, and the backup disk is a bit-to-bit clone of the original disk.
Although it's not exactly that, one can call this an "incremental" backup.

I would like to know if it's possible to do the same with my system disk, *i.e.* to once daily update a system drive copy in order to maintain a bit-to-bit clone that would be immediately bootable. Not by re-copying each time the whole system drive, but like for my data drive, just by adding/deleting once a day the slight amount of data which have daily changed.

Apart from building a RAID1 including my system disk, which implies letting the RAID running permanently, is there another way?
I didn't find any application that can bit-to-bit clone a system disk in such an "incremental" way.

Comment: Thank you for taking me at my word by putting me "-1", but it would have been nicer to answer me. Is it that trivial? Many people are interested in this question, but I seem to be the only one asking it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally answer to my own question, in case someone would have the same wonder.

There is no app that can incrementially update a bit-to-bit clone drive. Such app are making disk images, which are not immediatly bootable and need first to be installed (nevertheless more quickly than installing Windows).

The only way to update a ready-to-use backup system drive is to totally re-clone it regularly, for instance with a standalone cloning dock station.

I give generously myself a "+1" rating.